# is it possible to update the rsync from source

Tags: centos, rsync

Now I want to upgrade the rsync from 3.1.2 to 3.2.7, and I do it like this:

```
wget -c https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/src/rsync-3.2.7.tar.gz
tar -zxvf rsync-3.2.7.tar.gz
cd rsync-3.2.7
./configure
make && make install
```

all steps run success, but when I check the version, it still 3.1.2:

```
[root@k8smasterone rsync-3.2.7]# rsync --version
rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2015 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, symlinks, IPv6, batchfiles, inplace,
    append, ACLs, xattrs, iconv, symtimes, prealloc

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.
```

Am I missing something? this is the OS info:

```
[root@k8smasterone rsync-3.2.7]# uname -a
Linux k8smasterone 3.10.0-1160.31.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 10 13:32:12 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have already tried to configure like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/bin/
```

did not work.

Comment: What gives `/usr/bin/rsync --version`? Did you uninstall `rsync` from your package manager?